# What kind of terminal is this, and how can I fix it?

Tags: electrical, wiring, stove

So I have 3 damaged wires that I need to add new terminals to. The picture below is of the same type of terminal. What type of terminal is it, and how can I add the same kind of terminal to a stripped wire?

[image]
[image]

I need to add terminals to these wires (I need to splice the two black wires with one terminal):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called a spade connector, or spade lug terminal. You are holding a female connector.

You can purchase these at an electronics supply shop. As you might expect, they are available in a bewildering variety of styles and sizes. You might want to bring one of your connectors for identification.

Some are designed to be soldered onto the end of a wire, and others are made to crimp on using a bespoke tool. Either way, I think you'll find that heat-shrink tubing makes an excellent protective insulation.

Comment: Well, there's 3/16, 1/4 and 5/16, I wouldn't say a bewildering variety.

Comment: And single-grip, double-grip, with and without locking detent, bare or jacketed. Spades are solid or preforated. Crimp join may be a soft seamless tube or a split tube. Solder join may be a channel, a tube, or a solder lug with a hole, with or without a couple of sharp-edged and frustrating tabs to be bent around the insulated portion of the wire to hold it steady until the plastic melts I should stop now.

Comment: I would also add the variety of wire sizes to complete the list.

Comment: This looks more like a rather weird kind of quick connect than a spade lug...

Comment: And high temp spade terminals used in ovens to add to the assortment. Many wire cutters have crimps built in. For insulated crimps use the smooth or somewhat oval shaped crimp, for noninsulated use the crimp that has a pin to crimp, the crimp with the pin will damage the insulating sleeve so it should not be used on insulated crimp conductors according to the listing instructions. – Ed Beal 5 mins ago   delete

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Could you recommend the parts I’d need to make this repair?

Comment: I can tell you how I would do it. I would bring the part with the spade that needs to receive the connector to my local electronic supply shop and try out connectors until I found a fit. If I couldn't carry off the part, I might remove a wire harness with a matching connector and take that to the shop. If I couldn't remove anything, I would measure the spade, then cut and file down a scrap of brass to match it exactly and take the scrap to the shop.

Comment: My local shop is the You-do-it Electronics Center at 40 Franklin St in Needham, MA, but this probably doesn't help you because it's not a national chain. Try "electronic store near me" in your favorite search index.